# How to use the useState hook to handle multiple textInputs that are dynamic from a FlatList in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, react-native-textinput

---

I have a functional component that is a screen and I need to handle some state. I do not want to refactor my code to make it a class component and I would like to make use of hooks. I have a component within the screen that renders a flatlist (from JSON) of a product description, quantity and a box for a user input quantity. Currently my state for all the input quantities is tied together, so when I enter a number into 1 box, that same number is displayed in all boxes. How can I seperate and store the input state using hooks?

There is a lot of examples online with using hooks to store 1 peice of data but not multiple and as I do not know how many 'products' there will be a head of time I cannot create different useState's for them. Am I best having 1 useState for all the input boxes and stored in an array?

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, FlatList } from "react-native";

function InstallScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  // State for the number installed component
  const [quantityInstalled, setQuantityInstalled] = useState([]);

  const { item } = route.params;

  // pulling just the product arrays from the job data and storing separately
  const productData = item.products;

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerNine}>
      <View style={styles.descriptionBoxContainer}>
        <View style={styles.descriptionBox}>
          <FlatList
            data={productData}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <DescriptionBox
                productDescription={item.description}
                dueQuantity={item.quantity}
                value={quantityInstalled}
                onChangeText={(value) => setQuantityInstalled(value)}
              />
            )}
          />

          <Text>Number installed is {quantityInstalled} </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Description Component

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const DescriptionBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.productsAllContainer}>
      <View style={styles.descriptionBoxStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.productDescription}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.qtyBoxStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.qtyTextStyle}>{props.dueQuantity}</Text>
      </View>

      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.installedBoxStyle}
          textAlign="center"
          fontSize="18"
          fontWeight="bold"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          keyboardType={"numeric"}
          maxLength={5}
          value={props.value}
          onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not used react native, but what I usually do is make the name, the id of the item in the list then pass that name up when changing the state

```
<input name={id} onChange={onChange} />
```

then having one call to use state but make the on change function get the name from the event handler

```
  const [productQuantity, setProductQuantity] = React.useState('')
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setProductQuantity({...productQuantity,[name]:value})
  };
```

however for your specific case you'd also probably need a function to get the installed quantity from the state, you could also pass down a function to the child to do this along the lines, of

```
  const getProductQuantity = (id) => (
    productQuantity[id] && productQuantity[id] || 0
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a common answer for both React and React-Native**

You can use "useState" hook to store a single object with multiple properties for each input. And I think the below example will be helpful in your case as well.

```
// State
const [data, setData] = useState({
  name: '',
  email ''
})

// Elements
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" onChange={(e) => 
setData({ ...data, name: e.target.value })} />
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" onChange={(e) => 
setData({ ...data, email: e.target.value })} />
```

In here I used this "`setData({ ...data, name: e.target.value })`" peace of code line to update the existing state object by replacing particular keys with new values.